# How to replicate Matlab ARIMA model simulation in python?

Tags: python, matlab, statsmodels, arima

I have a task of replicating matlab's ARIMA model simulation in python. I'm currently using statsmodels' ARIMA model but I'm open for changing to another package. I understand that results will not be identical but I would think they should be comparable distribution wise.

In Matlab I'm doing `arima_model.simulate(steps, exog, paths, residuals, disturbances)`. I've been trying to replicate it with `arima_model.simulate(nsimulations=steps, exog=exog, anchor='end', repetitions=paths)`, I realise that I haven't specified residuals and disturbances in python, because I'm on unsure of the right specification. I can see that python requires length of residuals and disturbances to be equal to nsimulations, whereas Matlab seem to only use the last `steps` indices of residuals and disturbances, should I simply slice them equivalently in python? Additionally, I would think that the full specification should be `arima_model.simulate(nsimulations=steps, exog=exog, anchor='end', repetitions=paths, measurement_shocks=smoothed_state, state_shocks=residuals)` where `smoothed_state` is taken from the fitted ARIMA model and equivalent to Matlab's disturbances.

I've tried to remove residuals and disturbances from the simulation in Matlab but I still can't get similar results in python when I'm comparing the distribution of sum of each path. I've tested them with a Kolmogorov Smirnov test and they are not from the same distribution.